# django: why is getting model's .id field in template slow?

Tags: django, performance, optimization, django-models, django-templates

I have a template which ends up outputting about 700 input elements like this one:

```
<input class="ticket" size="3" maxlength="15" type="text" name="{{ ticket.id }}">
```

Together with calling the view function and rendering the template (generating the HTML, but not counting browser render time), it takes ~1.5 seconds. I was optimizing the template to see what was taking the longest, as there were a bunch of other more complicated things going on... and I realized if I removed the `{{ ticket.id }}` part, the render time went down to ~0.48 seconds. I even made a function on the ticket model:

```
def get_input_name(self): return str(self.id)
```

and replaced the line in the template:

```
<input class="ticket" size="3" maxlength="15" type="text" name="{{ ticket.get_input_name }}">
```

and this generated identical output, at ~0.52 seconds.

Why is calling `{{ ticket.id }}` so much slower?

Comment: Probably beacause it makes an extra SQL call, although not really sure about that, try profiling using something like http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-debug-toolbar-django13/0.8.4

Comment: What back-end are you using, and how many lines do you have in your Ticket Model ?

Comment: @nicolas: postgresql, 10 fields in my ticket model

Comment: @Claudiu: Do you have this issue with sqlite, for example?

Comment: @nicoals: not sure, i've only tried it with postgresql

Comment: Bizarre.  Is this still a problem?  What version of Django?  (I'm looking for optimizations for a slow template we have, and this looks like a possible easy win...) [Docs look like it should be the opposite, too](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/templates/#variables)

Comment: @Izkata: ah it's been 2 years and i haven't been using django regularly so i really don't know!

Comment: Oh well.  ~favs question~  I'll try and remember to come back here if I come up with anything...

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the SQL queries that are being executed. From the shell (`./manage.py shell`) try this:

```
from django.db import connection
from pprint import pprint
from django.http import HttpRequest
from myproject.myapp.views import myview
f = open('/tmp/queries.txt','w')
myview(HttpRequest(), whatever_other, args_you_need)
pprint(connection.queries, f)
f.close()
```

Then go look in `/tmp/queries.txt` and see what queries were actually being made. Each query will also have the time it took. If you don't see anything unusual (such as a query for every time through your template loop), then your issue is probably not the database, and I have no idea.